# When does Dagger2 create objects of dependencies defined in modules?

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2, dependency-management, dagger

I am using Dagger2 for DI. How should I group classes into a Component?

Does Dagger satisfy dependencies of all classes defined in a single @Component interface at runtime?

For example, if I have the following component:

```
@Component(modules = {ModuleA.class, ModuleB.class, ModuleC.class})
public interface Component {
   
   ClassA getClassA();
   ClassB getClassB();
   ClassC getClassC();
}
```

Here ClassA, ClassB and ClassC have overlapping dependencies but not exactly same.

Now when I call:

```
ClassA classA = DaggerComponent.create().getClassA();
```

Does Dagger2 create objects to satisfy all classes present in the Component or the classes only to satisfy `ClassA`?

Answer (score 0):

Analyzed the files created by Dagger on build.
It does in fact create the objects required only by classA when the following statement is called:

```
DaggerComponent.create().getClassA();
```